# javascript cannot search through innerHTML

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, innerhtml

i am trying to find tow many different texttypes are inside a innerhtml, somehow it doesn't find anything but when i test it with the same functions and a test sample it works.

```
    function numberoftext (a){if (a.match(/class=\"chattext\"/g)!==null){return a.match(/class=\"chattext\"/g).length;}else{return 0;}}
function numberofglobal (a){if (a.match(/class=\"chattextglobal\"/g)!==null){return a.match(/class=\"chattextglobal\"/g).length;}else{return 0;}}
function numberofclan (a){if (a.match(/class=\"chattextclan\"/g)!==null){return a.match(/class=\"chattextclan\"/g).length;}else{return 0;}}
function numberofgroup (a){if (a.match(/class=\"chattextgroup\"/g)!==null){return a.match(/class=\"chattextgroup\"/g).length;}else{return 0;}}
function numberofwisper (a){if (a.match(/class=\"chattextwhisper\"/g)!==null){return a.match(/class=\"chattextwhisper\"/g).length;}else{return 0;}}
function numberofworld (a){if (a.match(/class=\"worldsay\"/g)!==null){return a.match(/class=\"worldsay\">/g).length;}else{return 0;}}
function numberofscream (a){if (a.match(/class=\"chattextscream\"/g)!==null){return a.match(/class=\"chattextscream\"/g).length;}else{return 0;}}
var   innertextraw1 =chatupdateFrame.document.documentElement.innerHTML;
var innertextraw=    innertextraw1.substring(innertextraw1.indexOf("parent.chattextFrame.add(")+26, innertextraw1.indexOf("', 0);"));

console.log("got update",innertextraw);
console.log("t:",numberoftext(innertextraw),"c:",numberofclan(innertextraw),"w:",numberofwisper(innertextraw),"gr:",numberofgroup(innertextraw),"gl:",numberofglobal(innertextraw),"sc:",numberofscream(innertextraw));
```

an example for innertextraw is: `"<p class=\"chattext\"><i><b>noone</b> goes with <b>someone</b> to the house</i></p>"`

testing it like [that](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwaViIWDQIx-YXdfV2tfbGNmb28/view) works fine also when i set innertextraw to the example which i got from the console log, in the website it returns just 0.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape your `"` quotes to match escaped quotes in a string.

```
a.match(/class="chattext"/g)
```

In a real string, those escape slashes don't actually exist, there's just no way to represent a literal double (or single) quote if the string is using that character as a delimiter, so you have to escape it.

Here's a working example:

```js
var innerRawText = "<p class=\"chattext\"><i><b>noone</b> goes with <b>someone</b> to the house</i></p>";

var result = innerRawText.match(/class="chattext"/g);
console.log(result);
```